# Reading list recommendation for a hep-ph student to start studying QFT at a more mathematically rigorous level?

Tags: book-recommendation, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

**Edition**

On July 15 2021, the description of the question has been considerably modified to meet the requirement of making this question **more OP-independent** and thus more useful for general readers. But the **central point is the same**.

**One sentence summarization**

For a student initially working on a more **phenomenological** side of the high energy physics study, what is the **recommendation of introductory reading materials** for him/her to dive into a more **mathematically rigorous study** of the quantum field theory.

**Elaboration**

1. "phenomenology side of the high energy physics study" basically means that when this student uploads his/her article to arXiv, he/she will, in principle, **choose hep-ph as the primary archive**. This background also indicates that this student has, in general, already learned at least

   a. Undergraduate level physics classes;

   b. QFT from the first half of Peskin and Schroeder's classical textbook, or, maybe, Greiner's *Field Quantization*;

   c. Complex analysis like those covered in the first five chapters of Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*;

   d. Special function;

   e. Elementary set theory;

   f. General topology like those covered in Amstrong's *Basic Topology*;

   g. Elementary vector space theory with no details about the operator algebra;

   h. Some elementary conclusions from group theory, with a focus on the Lie group and Lorentz group;

   i. Enough particle physics so that he/she is able to understand what the summary tables of the PDG are talking about, or he/she at least knows how to find the definition of some of those unknown symbols.
2. "more mathematically rigorous study of quantum field theory" may have different meanings for different people. Just to give an example, Prof. Tachikawa from IPMU had a talk titled "Mathematics of QFT, by QFT, for QFT" on his website (https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/transp/qft-tsukuba.pdf),  which the OP find really tasteful, of course, from a rather personal point of view. One may agree that all those studies covered there may be considered mathematically rigorous studies of quantum field theory. Or, one may agree on only part of them. Or, maybe the answerer thinks that some other researches also count. That is all OK. But, please **specify your altitude before elaborating your answer**. The answerer may also want to **specify explicitly for which subfield** he/she is recommending references. In the OP's understanding, "more mathematically rigorous study of quantum field theory" basically covers those topics

   a. Algebraic/Axiomatic QFT, Constructive QFT or the Yang-Mills millennium problem, which tries to provide a mathematically sounding foundation of QFT.

   b. Topological QFT or Cconformal QFT, which utilizes some fancy mathematical techniques to study QFT.

   c. Even some math fields stemming from QFT like those fields-awarding work done by Witten.
3. It is best that those "introductory reading materials" could focus on the **mathematical prerequisites** of that subfield. It will be really appreciated if the answerer could further explain **why** one has to know such knowledge before doing research in that subfield. Answers may choose from a really formal vibe or a physics-directing vibe when it comes to the general taste of his/her recommendation and may want to **point out that difference explicitly**. It is also a good recommendation if the answerer lists some **review paper, newest progress, or commentary-like article in that subfield** so that people wanting to dive into this subfield could get a general impression of that subfield.

**Additional comments**

1. In general, this is **not a career advice post**. But, if the answerer wants to say something about some real-life issues of both hep-ph or hep-th/math-ph research, or the transition between those two fields, please feel free and don't be shy.
2. I understand that there already exist some good similar recommendation list posts on this site, but, at least as I know, none of them focuses on the **transition from hep-ph to hep-th/math-ph**, which is the central point of this post. If there does exist such a post and someone has already offered a quite good answer, please commet.
3. Another way of formulating this question is the following. Please give a list of the **introductory courses** that a graduate student majoring in mathematical physics should learn, or maybe a list of those papers an advisor would recommend to a **first-year graduate student** majoring in mathematical physics. But, keep in mind that this student has already had **accomplished a Master's level of hep-th study**.
4. This question has also been crossposted on MathOverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397143/reading-list-recommendation-for-a-hep-ph-student-to-start-studying-qft-at-a-more).

Comment: Some tough questions to answer. It takes some time to get used to the dual cultures, so to speak, of Mathematicians and Physicists. If you are coming from Physics and would like to know about the mathematical language, it may be a good idea to learn about gauge theory from a mathematical point of view, and maybe about characteristic classes too. But that would only be at the level of classical field theory. There are researchers who have worked on the mathematical foundations of QFT. I am not an expert, but look up the works of A. Jaffe and J. Glimm. I am interested in the answers you may get.

Comment: @Malkoun Thank you very much for your comment. For sure I know Jaffe and Glimm and they are of course big figures in this field. But, just like the case with Atiyah, unfamiliar and unknown mathematical concepts are also a big obstacle for me to read their paper or book currently. "...learn about gauge theory from a mathematical point of view", maybe you could recommend some textbooks?

Comment: @Malkoun Also, does "gauge theory from a mathematical point of view" mean something like "gauge field is a connection and field strength is a curvature"? If that is true, it would be really appreciated if you could recommend me some subjects to learn in order to understand this sentence.

Comment: My journey was in the opposite direction, so to speak, from Math to Physics. I don't know what to recommend. I have learned from various sources. There is a book by Jurgen Jost called Geometry and Physics. But it is written for Mathematicians wanting to learn Physics. I have had a standard North American Math education at the Graduate level. It included Boothby's book on differentiable manifolds, which I supplemented with 2 of Do Carmo's books (the undergraduate one on curves and surfaces and the Riemannian geometry one) and also Chern's book on complex manifolds (without potential theory).

Comment: But what you need is differential geometry and gauge theory for Physicists. I am sure it exists. Searching for related keywords on the internet showed that there is a book by Chris J Isham called "Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists". This may be a good reference for translating back and forth between both languages. I also found "Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists" by Marián Fecko. I generally like David Tong's lectures. He has notes on gauge theory <http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html>.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation on the differential manifold and differential geometry for the understanding of gauge theory! So how about algebraic topology, or maybe algebraic geomrty? I don't know whether those topics are relevant in the mathematically rigorous study of QFT and if it do pertain to this research, where should I start? Also, could you maybe tell me where I could find a list of the curriculum for a standard North American Math education at the Graduate level? Up till now, I have never been educated in North American, so I don't know the details.

Comment: I think the list I am seeking, in principle, should be a subset of this set which is obviously a little bigger for me.

Comment: It is not realistic to go through the whole list indeed. Perhaps start with Chris J Isham's book "Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists" together with David Tong's lecture notes on gauge theory? You can also use this website to look up and/or ask questions about connections and curvature. As for the curriculum, look up for instance a specific university, go to its website, and look at the list of courses. You can often click on a course website and find the textbook(s) they are using for it etc.

Comment: @Malkoun Thank you very much! I think previously I had some misunderstanding. I thought that differential geometry/topology and algebraic topology is two distinctly different things. But in fact, they are highly interconnected with each other. And in principle books about differential geometry will also cover algebraic topology to some extent.

Comment: Differential topology studies smooth (or if you prefer differentiable) manifolds and their invariants. Differential geometry studies Riemannian manifolds, which are smooth manifolds endowed with a Riemannian metric. Algebraic topology studies algebraic invariants of topological spaces. These topics are indeed highly interconnected. It is I believe for pedagogical reasons that a first course in any of these topics usually does not focus on the various connections with the other topics.

Comment: @Malkoun Thank you for your explanation. So, in my naive understanding, differential topology and geometry are basically the same thing, other than the settings, or the arenas, are different, but still somewhat connected. And algebraic topology is to use algebra to study topological structure. But then what is algebraic geometry? According to Wikipedia, it seems that this subject is the reverse of algebraic topology, which utilize geometric method to study the space of the solution of an equation. And does it has some connection with the mathematically rigorous study of QFT?

Comment: BTW, so why the naming of those subjects so unsystematical? For example, you see that differential geometry and topology, basical the same, both study differentiable whatwhat. The difference lies in the whatwhat, one of them ordinary manifold, and another a special manifold. This is basically the naive understanding that one will immediately get from the adjective-noun structure of their name. But when it comes to algebraic topology and geometry, even though the same structure, one of them seems to apply algebraic technique to study topological structure, and one of them the reverse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127428/discussion-between-malkoun-and-qi-tianluo).